# Diagonalizability in $\mathbb C$

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

Let $M \in M_{3}(\mathbb R)$ such that $\chi_{M}$ only has one root in $\mathbb R$. Show that M is diagonalizable in $\mathbb C$.

My steps so far:

Let $\lambda \in \mathbb R$ be the root. That means $\chi_{M}=(X-\lambda)f$, whereby $f$ irreducible in $\mathbb R$ and $\deg f = 2 $. Since, however, $\mathbb C$ is algebraically closed, it means that every polynomial is reducible into degree $1$ factors. So that means $M$ has either 2 or 3 eigenvalues in $\mathbb C$. In either case,

Algebraic multiplicity = Geometric multiplicity.

Therefore diagonalizable in $\mathbb C$.

Comment: How do you know geometric multiplicity = algebraic multiplicity if it has 2 roots in $\mathbf C$?

Comment: If $f$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{R}$ and $\deg(f)=2$ has two different roots in $\mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your argument, if $M$ had only two eigenvalues then one of would have algebraic multiplicity 2, but there's no reason why the geometric multiplicity would be $2$ as well.

---

We need to assume that $\chi_M$ has only one real root *of degree $1$*, otherwise the result is not true.

Here's a hint: Let $\lambda$ be the real root of the characteristic polynomical $\chi_M$, so $\chi_M(x)=(x-\lambda)^{I}p(x)$, where $p(x)$ is real of degree $2$. The roots of $p(x)$ are not real, so prove that if $\alpha$ is a root then $\overline{\alpha}$ is another root. $3$ distinct roots $\iff$ $3$ distinct eigenvalues $\Rightarrow$ diagonalizable.

---

Example for degree of the real root $=3$:
$$M=\begin{bmatrix}1&1&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$$
is not diagonalizable.

---

Note that if $\lambda$ had degree $2$ in $\xi_M$, then the same argument as in the solution, writing $\xi_M(x)=(x-\lambda)^2p(x)$ would yield $p(x)$ of degree $1$, so it would have a real root, which would need to be equal to $\lambda$ from the assumption in the exercise, so $\lambda$ would actually have degree $3$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

The characteristic polynomial has three **different** roots because the two complex non-real ones are a conjugate pair (as the polynomial is real), and thus the matrix is diagonalizable.

Comment: @Ins Yes, of course: that polynomial has **three** (equal) *real* roots...Not your case.

Comment: and because we have three different roots, where each eigenspace $\neq 0$ the algebraich multiplicity is equal to the geometric multiplicty.

Comment: Just for clarity's sake, why would $M$ not be diagonalizable if $f$ had two equal complex roots?

Comment: Exactly to your first comment above, and a **real** polynomial of degree three cannot have two equal complex non-real roots. It either has three real roots or else only one real root and conjugate pair of complex non-real roots.